# Как добавить текст под фото одним смс? Bot Telegram PHP

Tags: php, telebot, бот

$msg_photo_id = $bot->sendPhoto($chat_id, "https://sciencepop.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1480623895_akita-inu-dog-photo-1.jpg")->getMessageId();

Как сделать текст под фото одним смс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'telebot/telebot.php';

$bot = new Telebot('ваш_токен_бота');

$photo = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'; // URL изображения
$text = 'Это пример текста';
$chat_id = 12345678; // ID чата, куда нужно отправить сообщение

$bot->sendPhoto($chat_id, $photo, $text)->getMessageId();
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю.... Но мне нужно внедрить в мою строку кода ....

Comment: Видно же, что в моем примере передаётся три параметра, не два

Comment: Да, но не пойму как в мою строку внедрить...